# WPF VB.NET : how to insert a notepad in listbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

I already used the code as below.

```
 Dim openfile1 = New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog With {.Filter = "Text (*.Text)|*.txt"}
        If (openfile1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(openfile1.FileName)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
            Next
        End If
```

This code serves on windows form, when I use in WPF there are no errors but can not display the contents of the notepad on the listbox. there is no other solution

Answer (score 0):

`File.IO.ReadAllLines` will return an array of strings and not a `collection`. You're better off using a `For` loop.

```
  Dim openfile1 = New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog With {.Filter = "Text (*.Text)|*.txt"}
            If (openfile1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
                For i = 0 To Ubound(File.ReadAllLines(openfile1.FileName),1)
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(File.ReadAllLines(openfile1.FileName)(i))
                Next
            End If
```

`Foreach` statement = You need a `collection` object

Comment: Sorry..
I have to get solution of my colleagues. mistakes are on System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult